# Find Line numbers of content in a Div jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divheight = $("div").height(); 
    var lineheight = $("div").css('line-height').replace("px","");
    alert(Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)));
});
```

Iam trying to find number of lines of some content in one div. div height will be fixed. How to solve? this please help.
https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/n94u3Lb2/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n94u3Lb2/2/ works fine after including jQuery

Comment: @anoop You have not selected Jquery framework extension in fiddle . Thus your code is not working. Check console. its giving $ is not defined . Your code is correct. Just select Jquery framework from left dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo for getting line numbers of dive content :

http://jsfiddle.net/brunoscopelliti/EPms9/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var divheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").height(); 
 var lineheight = $("#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude").css('line-height').replace("px","");
 alert(Math.round(divheight/parseInt(lineheight)));
});
```

```css
#startegy-sections-targeting-exclude {
 line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startegy-sections-targeting-exclude">
  Something strange... <br/>maybe it's fault of the measure unit<br/>PX!
</div>
```

Comment: if Div height is fixed then how its possible to get number of lines?